# How to set Node.js and NPM version numbers in a hosted VSO Build Agent?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, tfsbuild, build-automation, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Online you can now set build dependencies on the General tab of a build definition.

[image]

But.. is  there a way to set the version of Node.js and NPM?

It seems like a hosted build agent is currently using Node.js v0.12.7 and NPM v2.11.3 but I need Node.js v4.2+ and NPM v3.3+. Is there a way to enforce it?

P.S.: On-premise VSO build agent is not an option.

Comment: i have the same problem, i think the only solution is to build using your own custom build server with vsts build agent installed on it

Answer (score 9):

There is now a [Node Tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/tool/node-js) available. The link to software inventory shared by Daniel was very helpful, and I discovered the installer digging into the Node specs for Hosted VS2017 agent.

> Finds or downloads and caches the specified version of Node.js and adds it to the PATH

Try adding a Node Tool installer step before your node/npm steps.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like there's a lot of misunderstanding as to what "demands" are. A build with a specific demand **does not change what software is available on the build agent**. A "demand" is simply a method of a build task expressing what requirements it has, so it can run on an agent that has the desired demands satisfied (these are the build agent's "capabilities").

[This list of software](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/build/hosted-agent-pool#software) is what's on the hosted build agent. If it's not there, and you can't install it via `npm` or the like, then you're out of luck.