# Visual Studio Team Services Build yml npm test not recognized

Tags: node.js, build, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-devops

I'm trying to run an npm install and test on Visual Studio Team Services Build (configuring the build using YAML). I have the following definition.

** updated **

```
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: npm
```

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: "8.x"

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
  command: "custom"
  verbose: "false"
  customCommand: "install @angular/cli -g"
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
  verbose: "false"
- task: CmdLine@1
  inputs:
  filename: "ng"
  arguments: "test --watch=false --single-run=true --reporters=junit,progress"
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
  testResultsFiles: "**\test.xml"
  testRunTitle: "Jasmine Tests"

The install runs fine, but I get an error on the test step:

`85% chunk id optimization               86% hashing 87% module assets processing  88% chunk assets processing 89% additional chunk assets processing                          90% recording 91% additional asset processing    92% chunk asset optimization       94% asset optimization           95% emitting

2017-12-06T06:21:34.7643927Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
2017-12-06T06:21:34.7682485Z ##[section]Finishing: Run  Tests`

I'm using puppeteer to workaround lack of chrome to run the tests.

Comment: Just checking it seems that hosted agents are a bit limited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150823/how-to-set-node-js-and-npm-version-numbers-in-a-hosted-vso-build-agent in the UI based build version it seems there is a node update tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/tool/node-js but not available on yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, but not 100% satisfied with the solutiuon, posting here the progress and open points plus detailed info to reproduce it, hope it can help other and that we can refine it.

**Scenario:** I'm in the need of configuring CI on an Angular 4 project and running it under Visual Studio Team Service CI hosted environment, and I want to use the yaml based config.

**Issues that I have found:**

- Hosted enviroment come with old node version (1).
- Chrome is not installed by default on the hosted environment, phantom browser is not anymore a solution since it's an abandoned project.
- You need to install angular-cli globally.

The current working solution I got, steps:

**On your project:**

Open your command prompt, install puppeteer, karma-junit-reporter

```
npm install puppeteer karma-junit-reporter --save-dev
```

**Configure your karma.conf.js**

At the top of your file add the following line of code

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();
```

Then on the pluging sections (add karma-junit-reporter)

```
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'), // add karma-unit reporter
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
```

On the reporters section set junit reporter as a valid one,and configure it:

```
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul', 'junit']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '',
      outputFile: 'test.xml',
    },
```

Now it's time to add on the root of your project a file named .vsts-ci.yml (just pasted the raw content in this link: https://pastebin.com/0XpmpPrp)

```
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: npm
```

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: "Updating node to version 8.x"
  inputs:
    versionSpec: "8.x"

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "installing angular-cli"
  inputs:
  command: "custom"
  verbose: "false"
  customCommand: "install @angular/cli@1.0.2 -g"
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
  verbose: "false"
- task: CmdLine@1
  displayName: "run tests: ng test"
  inputs:
  filename: "ng"
  arguments: "test --watch=false --single-run=true --reporters=junit,progress"
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: "Publish Test Results (test.xml)"
  inputs:
  testResultsFiles: "**\test.xml"
  testRunTitle: "Jasmine Tests"

What it does:

- Update node version.
- Globally install angular-cli (I stick to the version that is being used in the package).
- Execute a noop command (I don't know why it's needed, but if I don't add this it breaks).
- Execute ng test (single run and using junit as reporter).
- Publish test results.

Tips and interesting posts I have found:

- Use the UI build tool to create the build, then there is an option to convert it to yaml.
- Node tool updated task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/tool/node-js
- Puppeteer and VSTS: http://benjaminspencer.me/post/14/headless-chrome-vsts
- Angular 4 and VSTS (I): https://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2016/12/integrating-angular-2-unit-tests-with.html
- Angular 4 and VSTS (II): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/05/17/integrating-angular-4-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/

Room for improvement:

- Avoid having to install angular-cli globally, tried to add a custom script to my package-json, but when I call something like "npm run test:ci" it's not recognized by the visual studio build runner.
- I would like to get rid of puppeteer, is karma-jsdom-launcher an option?

Answer (score 0):

Using this code instead:

```
queue: Hosted VS2017
steps:
- script: echo installing packages
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: npm install
  inputs:
    command: install
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: npm test
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: run test
```

BTW, you need add `@angular/cli` dependency in package.json to install angular cli during running npm install command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I get to a point where I'm able to update node to version 8.x, install angular-cli, use puppetter to avoid chrome dependency and use junit report, I can run test task but it does not end properly, my config (will post it in a response just to paste the yaml)

Comment: It's better to open new thread for new issue instead of update the original issue, because forum readers may be confused with the answer.

Comment: I will do, the thing is  the npm@1 doesnt work as well, you need to update npm, I think now I'm near to the solution, will post a new thread, and a link to it in the comments, thanks

Comment: Sorry I meant to run the test, you need first to update node / npm to a proper version, then you have to workaround the lack of browser on the hosted machine and phantom is not anymore a valid solution (use puppetteer), then you have to setup junit reporter. I will try to compile all the steps in an answer, hope it will shed some light to other developers.

Comment: Just posted the solution I found, @starian chen-MSFT really apprecciated if you can help me refining it, thanks.